# Meteor account email verify fails two ways

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have email hooked up on my dev box, and get a verification email after creating a user.  I can click on the included link, and it will bring me to my main page.

1)  Clicking on the link seems to do some processing, because it redirects to /, but it does not change the verified flag on the user account.

2)  It seems to ignore my Accounts.config setting, and only works when I explicitly call

```
token = Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId)
```

Details:

```
mrt --version
Meteorite version 0.6.11
Release 0.6.5.1

mrt list --using

standard-app-packages
preserve-inputs
less
coffeescript
iron-router
foundation
http
moment
email
spin
roles
accounts-base
accounts-password
accounts-ui
```

Server/lib/account.coffee

```
Accounts.config
  sendVerificationEmail: true          
  forbidClientAccountCreation: true
```

server method:

```
Meteor.startup ->
  create_user = (options) ->
    console.log('create_user: ' + options.username)
    userId = Accounts.createUser options

    # should not be necessary, but I get email only when included
    token = Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId)


  Meteor.methods({ create_user: create_user })
```

After above called, mongo shows:

```
emails: [ { "address" : "jim@less2do.com" , "verified" : false}]

and

email: { "verificationTokens" : [ { "token" : "N3sLEDMsutTbjxyzX" , "address" : "jim@less2do.com" , "when" : 1.380616343673E12}]}
```

Get default email:

```
Hello,    
To verify your account email, simply click the link below.    
http://localhost:3000/#/verify-email/N3sLEDMsutTbjxyzX        
Thanks.
```

Clicking above link gets me to:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

But no changes to the mongo db.

I was expecting something pulled in by accounts-password processed /#/verify-email/N3sLEDMsutTbjxyzX and would update the user document.

accounts-base.js tries, with

```
match = window.location.hash.match(/^\#\/verify-email\/(.*)$/);
```

but the location hash is empty by this time.

Am I missing something where I need to manually set up routes?  Is my use of iron router ruining things?  Just in case,

```
Router.map ->
  this.route 'home',
    path: '/'

  this.route 'inboxes'
  this.route 'availability'
  this.route 'find-agent'
  this.route 'inbox-tour'
  this.route 'availability-tour'
  this.route 'find-agent-tour'

  this.route 'inbox', 
    path: '/inbox/:_id'
    data: () ->

      m = Messages.findOne this.params._id
      m._markRead()
      fixed = _.map m.history.versions, (msg) =>
        msg.left = (msg.author is 'offer')
        msg.body = msg.body.replace( /[\r\n]+/g, "<br>")
        msg
      m.history.versions = fixed
      Session.set  'messageVersions', fixed
      m

    waitOn: db.subscriptions.messages
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'

  this.route 'register',
  this.route 'requested',
  this.route 'blog',
  this.route 'test',
  this.route 'aboutUs'        

Router.configure
  layout: 'layout'

  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'

  loadingTemplate: 'loading'

  renderTemplates: 
    'footer': { to: 'footer' }
    'sidebar': { to: 'sidebar' }



  ### Commented to rule out this routine
  before: ->
    routeName = @context.route.name
    debugger

    # no need to check at these URLs
    #, etc 
    return  if _.include(["request", "passwordReset","register", "tour"], routeName)
    return  if _.intersection(routeName.split('-'), ["tour"]).length > 0
    return if routeName.indexOf('verify-email') != -'' 
    user = Meteor.user()
    unless user
      #@render (if Meteor.loggingIn() then @loadingTemplate else "/")
      if Meteor.loggingIn()
        console.log('still logging in, no user, to ' + @loadingTemplate)
        @render @loadingTemplate
        console.log('!render ' + @loadingTemplate + ' completed' )
      else
        console.log('no user, / from router over ' + @loadingTemplate)
        @render "home"
      @stop()
  ###
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm, this is now perfectly working. Here is what I do once I'm redirect to the root of the application.

**Read More**: [Verify an Email with Meteor Accounts](http://journal.gentlenode.com/meteor-20-how-to-verify-emails-with-meteor-account/).

```
// (client-side)
Template.Homepage.created = function() {
  if (Accounts._verifyEmailToken) {
    Accounts.verifyEmail(Accounts._verifyEmailToken, function(err) {
      if (err != null) {
        if (err.message = 'Verify email link expired [403]') {
          console.log('Sorry this verification link has expired.')
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Thank you! Your email address has been confirmed.')
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently there is a known issue with iron router and URLs that have hashbangs in the path, as the one it is generated with the email :

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/3

I suggest you try implement the same solution as the user samhatoum says (careful that I think since he put the code on the `extends` method in RootController has changed for `extend`.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have had a look there.  Thought iron router was... iron.  Never thought it would fail on such a baked in area of code.   Especially considering there is already money behind it (meteor, not I-R).  Will accept your answer shortly, just want to keep it on the attention list.  And the issue itself on github seems unresolved.

Comment: It seems that the author of the package thought it was already resolved, but then a couple of other users kept reporting the problem so guess it's not. I posted a comment on the issue thread to let the author know...

Comment: Hey guys, I think this should be fixed on the dev branch which will be released soon. Please post a bug on github if you still notice the issue on dev.